# Compare a date of two elements

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

My problem is difficult to explain :

In my website I save every action of my visitors (view, click, buy etc).
I have a simple collection named "flow" where my data is registered

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534d4a9a37e4fbfc0bf20483"),
    "profile" : ObjectId("534bebc32939ffd316a34641"),
    "activities" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("534bebc42939ffd316a3af62"),
            "date" : ISODate("2013-12-13T22:39:45.808Z"),
            "verb" : "like",
            "product" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("534bebc52939ffd316a3f480"),
            "date" : ISODate("2013-12-20T19:19:10.098Z"),
            "verb" : "view",
            "product" : "6"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("534bebc32939ffd316a3690f"),
            "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:11:44.902Z"),
            "verb" : "buy",
            "product" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("534bebc42939ffd316a3741b"),
            "date" : ISODate("2014-01-11T08:49:02.684Z"),
            "verb" : "favorite",
            "product" : "26"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to aggregate these data to retrieve the **number** of people who made an action (for example "view") and then another later in time (for example "buy"). To to that I need to compare "date" inside my "activities" array...

I tried to use aggregation framework to do that but I do not see how too make this request
This is my beginning :

```js
db.flows.aggregate([
    { $project: { profile: 1, activities: 1, _id: 0 } },
    { $match: { $and: [{'activities.verb': 'view'}, {'activities.verb': 'buy'}] }}, //First verb + second verb
    { $unwind: '$activities' },
    { $match: { 'activities.verb': {$in:['view', 'buy']} } }, //First verb + second verb,
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$profile',
            view: { $push: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$activities.verb", "view" ] } , "$activities.date", null ] } },
            buy: { $push: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$activities.verb", "buy" ] } , "$activities.date", null ] } }
        }
    }
])
```

Maybe the format of my collection "flow" is not the best to do what I want...If you have any better idea dont hesitate

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you post the sample document and the query in your question instead of referencing it to an external website?

Comment: Yes, it's good practice on SO to include it as `code` always

Answer (score 0):

Here is the aggregation that will give you the total number of buyers who viewed first and then bought (though not necessarily the same product that they viewed).

```
db.flow.aggregate(
      {$match: {"activities.verb":{$all:["view","buy"]}}}, 
      {$unwind :"$activities"},
      {$match: {"activities.verb":{$in:["view","buy"]}}},
      {$group: { 
          _id:"$_id",
          firstViewed:{$min:{$cond:{
                      if:{$eq:["$activities.verb","view"]},
                      then : "$activities.date",
                      else : new Date(9999,0,1) 
          }}},
          lastBought: {$max:{$cond:{
                      if:{$eq:["$activities.verb","buy"]},
                      then:"$activities.date",
                      else:new Date(1900,0,1)}
          }}}
      },
      {$project: {viewedThenBought:{$cond:{
            if:{$gt:["$lastBought","$firstViewed"]},
            then:1,
            else:0
      }}}},
      {$group:{_id:null,totalViewedThenBought:{$sum:"$viewedThenBought"}}}
)
```

Here you first pass through the pipeline only the documents that have all the "verbs" you are interested in.  When you group the first time, you want to use the earliest "view" and the last "buy" and the next project compares them to see if they viewed before they bought.

The last step gives you the count of all the people who satisfied your criteria.

Be careful to leave out all $project phases that don't actually compute any new fields (like you very first $project).  The aggregation framework is smart enough to never pass through any fields that it sees are not used in any later stages, so there is never a need to $project just to "eliminate" fields as that will happen automatically.

Answer (score -1):

For your query:

> I would like to aggregate these data to retrieve the number of people who made an action

Try this:

```js
db.flows.aggregate([
    // De-normalize the array into individual documents
    {"$unwind" : "$activities"}, 
    // Match for the verbs you are interested in
    {"$match" : {"activities.verb":{$in:["buy", "view"]}}}, 
    // Group by verb to get the count
    {"$group" : {_id:"$activities.verb", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

The above query would produce an output like:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "buy",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "view",
                        "count" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

**Note:** The `$and` operator in your query (`{ $match: { $and: [{'activities.verb': 'view'}, {'activities.verb': 'buy'}] }}`) is not required as that's the default if you specify multiple conditions.  Only if you need a logical OR, `$or` operator is required.

If you want to use the date in the aggregation query to do queries like how many "views by day", etc.. the [`Date Aggregation Operators`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I'm not expressed but it is not exactly what I need.
I want the count of action with verb "buy" only if an action with the verb "view" exists and is further. I want to do something like the site "mixpanel". I think to do that I need to use "date" in my data. 
I would like the statistics of actions that follow.

The best example to show what I want to do is the sankey diagram. I would like to be able with some mongo queries to draw a [sankey diagram](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey?hl=fr)

Answer (score -1):

I see where you are going with this and I think you are basically on the right track. So more or less un-altered (but for formatting preference) and the few tweeks at the end:

```js
db.flows.aggregate([
    // Try to $match "first" always to make sure you can get an index
    { "$match": { 
        "$and": [
            {"activities.verb": "view"}, 
            {"activities.verb": "buy"}
         ] 
    }},
    // Don't worry, the optimizer "sees" this and will sort of "blend" with
    // with the first stage.
    { "$project": { 
        "profile": 1, 
        "activities": 1, 
        "_id": 0 
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$activities" },
    { "$match": { 
        "activities.verb": { "$in":["view", "buy"] } 
    }}, 
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$profile",
       "view": { "$min": { "$cond": [ 
           { "$eq": [ "$activities.verb", "view" ] },
           "$activities.date",
           null 
       ]}}, 
       "buy": { "$max": { "$cond": [ 
           { "$eq": [ "$activities.verb", "buy" ] },
           "$activities.date",
           null 
       ]}} 
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "viewFirst": { "$lt": [ "$view", "$buy" ] }
    }}
])
```

So essentially the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) operators should be self explanatory in the context in that you should be looking for the "first" view to correspond with the "last" purchase. As for me, and would make sense, you would actually be matching these by product (but **hint**: "Grouping") but I'll leave that part up to you.

The other advantage here is that the `false` values will always be negated if there is an actual date to match the "verb". Otherwise this goes through as `false` and this turns out to be okay.

That is because the next thing you do is [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to "compare" the values and ask the question "Did the 'view' happen before the 'buy'?" which is a logical evaluation of the "less than" [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/#exp._S_lt) operator.

As for the schema itself. If you are storing a lot of these "events" then you are probably better off flattening things out into separate documents and finding some way to mark each with the same "session" identifier if that is separate to "profile".

Getting away from large arrays ( which this seems to lead to ) if likely going to help performance, and with care, makes little different to the aggregation process.